# Home intent launching SettingsActivity instead of MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm workin on an android launcher on eclipse, the package containst MainActivity which is the launcher itself and SettingsActivity.

My problem is that if I open the settings page, go somewhere else and I click on the home button I get taken to the settings page (instead of directly to MainActivity) it's like it remembers i've opened settings.

This is an excerpt from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<!-- Launcher-->
<activity
    android:name=".launcher.MainActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- Settings -->
<activity
    android:name=".launcher.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/launcher_settings_name"
    android:theme="@style/android:Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can see that the Launcher responds to the home intent, and SettingsActivity responds to it's own intent from the launcher.

How can I make sure that the home intent takes users directly to the launcher, no matter if the last activity of the app has been settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you've set Settings activity as your Launcher.

Try this,

```
<!-- Launcher-->
<activity
    android:name=".launcher.MainActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- Settings -->
<activity
    android:name=".launcher.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/launcher_settings_name"
    android:theme="@style/android:Theme.DeviceDefault" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was given the solution on a different question:

[Make home intent take to specific application activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190254/make-home-intent-take-to-specific-application-activity)

--

If you are trying to create a HOME-screen replacement, then the activity for that needs to have the following in its  tag in the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This will ensure that only one instance of this activity ever exists and that when this activity launches other activities that they will all go into new tasks and not be a part of the HOME-screen replacement's task.